# SSIS Lookup, create new records for no-match output and get newly generated keys

Tags: sql-server, ssis, lookup, etl, dataflow

I have a Hotel table.

```
 create table DimHotel
 (
  Hotel_ID int Identity(1, 1),
  HotelName nvarchar(max)
 )
```

Now i get some feeds as `HotelNames`, now our business logic is use `Hotel_ID` for existing HotelName and create new record for HotelName which is new and use newly generated  Hotel_ID. Now I understood that I can direct "Lookup No Match Output" to OLE DB Command Transformation but then how i get newly generated key. 
One option is do one more lookup on DimHotel table (I guess this is stupid, scanning a table twice). What other option do we have.

I can use but Merge statement but our ETL team wants to avoid hand coding.

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to use a stored procedure which retrieves the SCOPE_IDENTITY as an output parameter .

Example :-

```
     Create Procedure 
     (
      column names ,
      @id int 
     ) 
     AS
     BEGIN
     INSERT INTO TableName  VALUES (@col1)
     SELECT @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
```